# Combobox filter on multiple properties

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I'm making a window in wpf.

In that window I want to show a editable combobox.

I have binded this combobox with a viewmodel that contains a list of server objects. The server object has 2 properties, an IP-address and a servername.

Now I want to be able to type in an IP-address or servername and filter the combobox accordingly. I also want the results in the combobox to be shown as [IP-address - Servername]

How can I do this?

Comment: IsTextSearchEnabled = true ???

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the simplest way to produce your desired output is to implement the ToString() method in your server objects class:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("{0} - {1}", IpAddress, ServerName); 
}
```

Now each instance of the class will have its own display name when you add them to a collection control:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ServerObjects}" />
```

Then for searching, I believe that you can just set the `IsTextSearchEnabled` property to true. Let me know how it goes.